# Updating an Existing XML Document in Python

Tags: python, xml

I have a large XML file whose structure is approximately as follows:

```
<GROUNDTRUTH>
  <thing fileName="1" attrib="2">
    <SUBSUB moreStuff="12" otherStuff="13"/>
  </thing>
  <thing fileName="2" attrib="2">
    <SUBSUB moreStuff="12" otherStuff="13"/>
  </thing>
  <thing fileName="3" attrib="2">
    <SUBSUB moreStuff="12" otherStuff="13"/>
  </thing>
</GROUNDTRUTH>
```

I don't think I was clear enough in the original posting of this question. I have an xml document called `GROUNDTRUTH`, and inside of that I have several thousand "things". I want to search through all of the things in the document via filename and then change an attribute. So if I was searching for `fileName="2"`, I would change its attribute to `attrib=x`. And for some `thing`, perhaps I'd go down to the `sub` level and change `moreStuff`.

My plan is to store into a csv file the names of the 'things' I need to change, and what I want to change the value of 'attrib' to. What function or module will provide this kind of functionality? Or am I just missing an easy/obvious approach? Ultimately I'd like to have a working script that will take a csv file with the `thing` identifier, and value to be updated, and take the xml file to make those changes onto.

Thanks for your help and suggestions!

Comment: [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/)?

Comment: Have you heard about Google before?

Comment: Search **[python] xml replace attribute** in StackOverflow.com and you find many answers there.

Answer (score 1):

First, you can transform the original xml file into an outputted xml file using an [xslt](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/) stylesheet which can modify xml files in any way, shape, or form such as modifying, re-structuring, re-ordering attributes, elements, etc. Do note xsl is a declarative special-purpose language to transform and render XML documents.

Then, you can use Python's [lxml](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/lxml/3.4.0) library to run the transformation:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import lxml.etree as ET

dom = ET.parse('originalfile.xml')
xslt = ET.parse('transformfile.xsl')
transform = ET.XSLT(xslt)
newdom = transform(dom)

tree_out = ET.tostring(newdom, encoding='UTF-8', pretty_print=True)

xmlfile = open('finalfile.xml','ab')
xmlfile.write(tree_out)
xmlfile.close()
```

By the way, PHP, Java, C, VB, or pretty much any language, even your everyday browser can run transformations! To have the browser run it, simply add stylesheet in header:

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="transformfile.xsl"?>
```